# How to use Irrlicht with Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c

Irrlicht uses namespaces, a C++ feature not available in Objective-C:

```
/*
In the Irrlicht Engine, everything can be found in the namespace 'irr'. So if
you want to use a class of the engine, you have to write irr:: before the name
of the class. For example to use the IrrlichtDevice write: irr::IrrlichtDevice.
To get rid of the irr:: in front of the name of every class, we tell the
compiler that we use that namespace from now on, and we will not have to write
irr:: anymore.
*/
using namespace irr;
```

How can I still use Objecive-C with Irrlicht? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a forum thread](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=34035&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0) in which some people are trying to get the OpenGL ES branch to compile for iPhone; there are some instructions there, so you might have success with it in Objective-C.

Here is [another thread](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=38678&highlight=&sid=226a7d32cb83f2c6b6195554c40a136c) which covers some Objective-C Irrlicht problems.

At this point it's probably blatantly obvious I'm just searching around to try and help you. If these didn't help I'll just delete my answer, since I am obviously not (yet) a Mac guy. :(

Comment: I don't want to write for OpenGL ES. I didn't even mention something about iPhones. Objective-C is a platform-indepenent language. Sorry. (:

Comment: Sorry! I forgot, I always associate Objective-C with iPhone. Does the forum thread help? If not I can just delete my answer.

Comment: Well great! Glad I could help you then.